# iframe - getting URL from child and not parent site

Tags: javascript, php, html, iframe, parent-child

So I have a iframe on a webpage.

The iframe goes something like this:

```
<iframe width="854" height="670" src="https://server-link.org/Audio_1.html" allow="microphone" frameBorder="0"></iframe>
```

The website on which the content of this iframe is embedded on goes `https://survey.org/?PROLIFIC_PID=2222`, while 2222 is just an example. Each survey participant gets an individual combination of numbers here.

A bit of background: My html site (`https://server-link.org/Audio_1.html`) hosts a "tool" which allows participants to record a voice message. What I want now, is that each voice message gets stored with the Prolific_PID from above in its file name. So for instance: `Audio_1_2222.wav`. Up until now I always only come up with `Audio_1_undefined.wav`.

I used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14662731/can-i-get-the-url-of-iframe-parent-window-with-php/14662781) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4028094/getting-url-from-a-child-iframe) post, to include the http-referer `print_r($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);`. The output from this is "https://server-link.org/Audio_1.html". Also, if I go to "https://server-link.org/Audio_1.html?PROLIFIC_PID=2222" an audio file with the correct file name gets stored.

Well.. this however is the wrong URL, since my survey has the URL `https://survey.org/?PROLIFIC_PID=2222`.

Is there any way to tell my JS file, php or even iframe to use the survey URL to extract the PID? I think the link which is specified in the iframe in my case is the parent-site and the survey URL the child site?

Here is also a respective snippet of the js-file:

```
function Redirect()
{
        var currentUrl = window.location.href.split("?PROLIFIC_PID=");

    var urlChunks = currentUrl.toString().split('/');

    var currentQuestion = urlChunks[urlChunks.length - 1].split('.');

          if (currentUrl[0] == "server-link.org/Audio_1.html") window.location.href = "Audio_1.html" + "?PROLIFIC_PID=" + userID;
}
```

These are some of my very first encounters with iframes, js and php. Please bare with me :D

Comment: Can't you just use `https://server-link.org/Audio_1.html?PROLIFIC_PID=<?php echo $_GET['PROLIFIC_PID']; ?>` on the iframe URL?

Comment: Such a good idea.. this however unfortunately leaves me with a .wav called "Audio_1_%3C?php%20echo%20%24_GET%5B%27PROLIFIC_PID%27%5D;?%3E" - so basically just the iframe-src as URL-encoded. It doesnt seem to recognize the php command at all.. maybe this has also to do with the fact that I have to specifiy my iframe within a google sheets document (https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MYXY_CdmM43CSjkfwXPwBx3BNYQrr-7Pf-FSRbTnF8E/edit?usp=sharing) ..

Comment: The website where the iframe is needs to use PHP and needs to be in a PHP-enabled page (`.php` page).

Comment: I think I understand that it might not work from the google sheets document (probably since it doesnt recognize php? It does however recognize iframe tags, css, and so on).. but could you elaborate? :-/ right now my project consists of a html file (containing the look and content of the tool), a js file (containing the whole functionality of the tool) and a php file - this latter only contains commands to print out information about the uploaded wav-file (e.g. print_r($_FILES);) in the chrome dev tools.

Comment: I was able to solve the problem by editing the iframe in the google sheet with the help of a get appraoch via R (https://www.r-project.org/). <iframe width="854" height="670" src="server-link/Audio_1.html?PROLIFIC_PID=`r PROLIFIC_PID`" allow="microphone" frameBorder="0"></iframe>

Comment: @JM-AGMS your idea eventually helped me come up with the solution to enter the parameter into the iframe url. Thanks so much!

Comment: That's great, glad you worked it out. Can you still post the answer to your own question? It could maybe help those with similar problems in the future.